# How to delete entire function definition (C style)

Tags: cursor-motions, normal-mode

How can I delete the block

```
int Test()
{
//
}
```

when my cursor is before `int` (or even better when it is anywhere on that line)?

The shortest I could come up with is `d<line>G` where `<line>` is the line number of the closing brace, or `d<diff>j` where `<diff>` is the difference of the line number. I am not happy with either.

Comment: What about `V][d`?

Comment: @Hotschke I like it

Comment: An alternative: `Vj%d`

Comment: Related question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8221/jumping-to-start-end-of-function-definition-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Motion `][`: next `}` in the first column

`V][d` does what you want. More details can be found under [`:h ][`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%5D%5B) and [`:h section`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#section):

```
                            *section*
[...]
The "]" and "[" commands stop at the '{' or '}' in the first column.  This is
useful to find the start or end of a function in a C program.  Note that the
first character of the command determines the search direction and the
second character the type of brace found.
```

Furthermore, vim's user manual has dedicated a paragraph about them within section  *29.3 Moving through a program* ([`:h 29.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_29.txt.html#29.3)).

[*Chapt. 50 Section Movement Theory*](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/50.html) in the free ebook [*Learn Vimscript the Hard Way*](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) by Steve Losh gives you more background about them and explains in a subsequent chapter how to adapt them for a new language.

#### Memorizing

If you are not familiar with the set of square bracket motions `[[`, `[]`, `]]`, `][` and [you struggle memorizing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/make-sense-of?noredirect=1&lq=1), maybe following grouping and hints help:

1. `[[` and `]]` jump to the *beginning* (i.e. `{`) of the current/previous and next function
2. `[]` and `][` jump to the *end* (i.e. `}`) of the previous and current/next function

As mentioned in the vim help page: the *first* square bracket you type determines the *direction* you move and the *second* bracket the *type* you are looking for. The second bracket is more difficult to grasp because the meaning can be seen as inconsistent: `[` relates not to `{` and `]` not to `}`.
I memorize it as

1. *beginning* of function: square bracket must be *repeated*
2. *end* of function: square bracket must be *alternated*

#### Are these not too specific to be generally useful aka exotic?

I think it is worthwhile to learn them: many languages use curly braces. Additionally, ftplugins in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin` override them for many languages, which are not curly brace based, most prominently *python*, *ruby*, *sql*, and *vimscript*. They offer semantic equivalents for the respective languages.

Also third party ftplugins for *latex* ([vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex)), *markdown* ([vim-markdown by plasticboy](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown)), *html/xml* ([xml.vim](https://github.com/othree/xml.vim)), *manpages* ([vim-man](https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-man)) and more remap them ([fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive), [jumpy.vim](https://github.com/arp242/jumpy.vim)).

Note there are different expectations of what the equivalents should be. For instance, [*pythonsense*](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-pythonsense) provides alternatives for python. For markdown there are also several plugins which offer different versions: [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown), [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc), [gabrielelana/vim-markdown](https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown), [pandoc-sections.vim](https://github.com/gbgar/pandoc-sections.vim).

**UPDATE**
[nvim-treesitter-textobjects](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects) suggests to use them for [movement in classes](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects#text-objects-move). IMHO this limits the usefulness of them: they should apply to classes and methods since pressing `[[` and `]]` is quick and navigating functions is more common.

#### *Egyptian* Brackets

For code which uses [Egyptian Brackets](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1.2-blocks-k-r-style) for functions and classes, vim help suggests to customize `[[, [], ]], ][`:

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings: >
   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
[type these literally, see |<>|]
```

Typical languages are java, rust and go. Actually, the end of function motions could be left unchanged. `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/rust.vim` and the third-party plugin [vim-go](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) remap only `[[` and `]]` for you. Also `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/php.vim` remaps only `[[` and `]]` to jump to keywords like `function` or `class` regardless whether Egyptian style is used.

Also the plugin [lh-dev](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev/#function) by Luc Hermitte tries to help here.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph (`ip, ap`) and curly brace (`i{, a{`) motions are good for this. The curly braces may need to be forced linewise with `Va}`, but they still wont capture the method declaration.

If, like me, you put blank lines between methods, the paragraph motion is suitable and succinct (and does not require memorization of which square bracket does what). `dap` (or `dVap`) rolls off my fingers because I use it so frequently.

Comment: I also quite like `ip/ap`. However, usually you cannot be sure that there are no blank lines within a function/method. Also `iB/aB` (= `i{/a{` = `i}/a}`) do not select the 'header' line of the function (`int Test()`).

Comment: @Hotschke agreed, i hadnt thought about the inner body much. Though id argue blank lines in the body is an opportunity for refactoring :P i noted in answer about the declaration line.

Comment: `va{V` will capture the header declaration too

Comment: @SebastianNielsen isnt that the same as Va{, which I mention? And that’s only true in a style with the curly brace on the same line as the decl

Comment: @D.BenKnoble For me `Va{` yeilds the same as `va{`, but that might just be because I am using .ideavim -- which is known to be rather buggy, and I can surely attest to that!

Answer (score 1):

Vim often provides many ways to do things! Here are a couple of alternatives to the existing answers:

### Using [%](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%25)

<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

- <kbd>V</kbd> Enter linewise visual mode
- <kbd>j</kbd> Move down to the opening bracket
- <kbd>%</kbd> Jump to the matching closing bracket
- <kbd>d</kbd> Delete the selected text

## Using a [forced linewise motion](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#forced-motion)

- <kbd>d</kbd> delete
- <kbd>V</kbd> (forcing the next motion to be linewise)
- <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> [as far as the closing bracket](https://vimhelp.txt.html#%5D%5B)