# What is a "section" in vim?

Tags: movement

I'm trying to improve my ability to move around inside files in vim, especially using built-in mappings/commands. I edit a lot of different types, including shell, markdown, Python, etc. I'm familiar with the `{` and `}` keys, which move between paragraphs (in fact, anything with a blank lines separating them, which is useful even when writing code), as well as other keys of course.

However, I'm reading about the `[[`, `[]`, `][`, and `]]` keys, which seem designed for moving between ['sections'](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%5D%5D). However, reading about sections in the vim documentation doesn't really help much; it seems to be written in terms of 'nroff', which I'm vaguely familiar with but isn't a file format I really know much about, or use. None of the filetypes I deal with seem to recognise those mappings/keys.

This makes me think that it would be useful to repurpose/rebind them. However, is there some non-nroff-specific meaning to a section? If so, how do I exploit/use it/turn it on?

Comment: The book *Learn Vimscript the Hard Way* by Steve Losh has a little bit of background about [Section Movement Theory](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/50.html). A related question is [Make sense of <section movements>](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/make-sense-of).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initial usage of these mapping is to navigate between functions in C files as said in [`:h section`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#section) (note it's not the same topic as [`:h 'sections'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27sections%27) that you linked in your question)

> ```
> The "]" and "[" commands stop at the '{' or '}' in the first column.  This is
> useful to find the start or end of a function in a C program.
> ```

So this is the definition of the section as Vim understands it: An arbitrary number of lines delimited by curvy brackets on the first column of a line.

Note that it is only if the curvy bracket characters are on the first column like in this code:

```
int main()
{
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

If your code doesn't follow this convention the help advises to remap the keys so that they look for curvy brackets anywhere in the line:

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings: 

   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
```

This is better but not ideal so it is sometimes a good idea to remap them to achieve the same purpose (e.g. navigate between functions) but for different filetypes. An example is in the standard `vim` ftplugin [shipped with vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/e52702f00322c8a8861efd0bd6a3775e685e5685/runtime/ftplugin/vim.vim#L65-L73) and neovim:

```
nnoremap <silent><buffer> [[ m':call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "bW")<CR>
vnoremap <silent><buffer> [[ m':<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "bW")<CR>
nnoremap <silent><buffer> ]] m':call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "W")<CR>
vnoremap <silent><buffer> ]] m':<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('^\s*fu\%[nction]\>', "W")<CR>
nnoremap <silent><buffer> [] m':call search('^\s*endf\%[unction]\>', "bW")<CR>
vnoremap <silent><buffer> [] m':<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('^\s*endf\%[unction]\>', "bW")<CR>
nnoremap <silent><buffer> ][ m':call search('^\s*endf\%[unction]\>', "W")<CR>
vnoremap <silent><buffer> ][ m':<C-U>exe "normal! gv"<Bar>call search('^\s*endf\%[unction]\>', "W")<CR>
```

In any buffer with a filetype `vim` the mappings will navigate through the function thanks to searches based on the keywords `function` and `endfunction` (and their short version).

Several other plugins do this but you can also do it by yourself for your favorite filetypes.

After a quick search in the standard runtime files I found that Vim remaps these keys for the following filetypes:

- abaqus
- cobol
- context
- eiffel
- hamster
- j
- mf
- mp
- python
- ruby
- rust
- vim
- zimbu

Comment: Hm i thought only [{ and friends handled curly braces. [[ also seemed more for .SH macros in nroff. Learned something today.

Comment: This is great, thanks, much clearer! This is very helpful. Probably worth pointing out that `[` and `]` are *not* commands, though, as that help page says. `[[` and `]]` are the actual keymappings. `[` and `]` are prefix keys for a family of keybindings, where `[` and `]` move by sections.

Comment: I wrote a [little plugin](https://github.com/arp242/jumpy.vim/) to map `[[`/`]]` for a bunch of filetypes (and also make it behave more consistent) which may be of interest @AndrewFerrier

Comment: @MartinTournoij thanks, that looks great!

Comment: @AndrewFerrier While you are at it, you may also have a look at [gbgar/pandoc-sections.vim](https://github.com/gbgar/pandoc-sections.vim) (not me!) for some more inspiration. It provides `i]] i][ a]] a][ I][` and `A][`. The plugin is currently not being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

[The accepted answer by statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25742/343) already covers what these days must be the main use case for `]]` and `[[`: jumping to lines that start with a curly brace character.

I thought I'd just clarify the rest of their behaviour, which is described in [`:help section`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#section).

It's actually simpler than you might be presuming. You don't really need to know anything about nroff markup* to understand it: it just means that `]]` and `[[` will jump to any lines that start with a dot followed by any of the pairs of characters in the [`'sections'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27sections%27) option. Try pasting the following into a buffer and using `]]` and `[[`:

```
...
...
.SH The
...
...
.NH cursor
...
...
...
.H stops
...
...
...
.HU here,
...
.nh here,
...
...
.XX here if you :set sections+=XX
...
.sh and here.
...
...
...
```

The commands will also stop at a line that begins with a `CTRL-L` character. This is slightly harder to include in an answer, but you can add such a line to your buffer by typing <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, starting from normal mode.

This last one is probably the only part of the above that *isn't* nroff-specific: I've seen CTRL-L characters used to divide C/C++ files into sections, and this character also appears to be ignored by the Python interpreters I have installed. I suspect it's safe to use it for this purpose in a fair number of file formats.

<sub>* [nroff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nroff) is a text-formatting program which is used for writing man pages. It takes marked-up text as input and outputs formatted text. You can think of an "nroff macro" as being similar to an HTML tag.</sub>